# How to get macOS to appear on startup

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, apple

I have iMac 2013 running ubuntu and wanted to know how to get the boot loader to appear?,which would in return should theoretically show a list of all the operating systems that I have on my computer allowing me to boot my Mac Os instead of Ubuntu which it is loading up now by default every time ever since I installed it.

Comment: Were you asked to install beside the Mac OS during the Ubuntu install? What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I installed refind boot loader it simplified the process and very efficient

Comment: How is this an answer. If this could be an answer it needs a lot more detail.

Comment: Actually it's almost self-evident the way it is.